# Converter arrays para hash

Tags: array, hash, perl, map

Estou dando algumas manutenções em um sistema em Perl (linguagem que sou noob) e precisei criar um novo módulo de relatório onde preciso resolver a seguinte situação:

Tenho 2 arrays com os seguintes formatos

```
@head = ("nomeinstituicao", "cnpjinstituicao","nomecliente", "cnpjcliente", "notacliente" );

@data = ("inst1", "12345678000112","joao", 
 "87654321000198","5","inst2","54387612000123","maria","45612387000123","6",...);
```

Preciso produzir um hash no seguinte formato:

```
%hash = (

"nomeinstituicao" => "inst1",
"cnpjinstituicao" => "12345678000112",
"nomecliente" => "joao",
"cnpjcliente" => "87654321000198",
"notacliente" => "5",
"nomeinstituicao" => "inst2",
"cnpjinstituicao" => "54387612000123",
"nomecliente" => "maria",
"cnpjcliente" => "45612387000123",
"notacliente" => "6",
...
);
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com uma forma de fazer esta transformação de maneira dinâmica levando em consideração que os dados contidos em `$data` estou buscando no BD.

Estou tentando o dia todo e não consegui até agora, tentei com `map` e com `while` mas acho que não estou fazendo certo.

Answer (score 0):

O que você precisa fazer é um de/para com os dados que você tem no banco com o *header* que você tem.

Outro ponto é que a forma como você manipula os dados provenientes do banco podendo ser eles em [array](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_array) ou [hashref](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref) por exemplo.

Pelo seu exemplo acredito que seja o primeiro caso com o result set sendo em um array.

Desse modo:

```
my @head = ('nomeinstituicao', 'cnpjinstituicao','nomecliente', 'cnpjcliente', 'notacliente' );

my @data = ('inst1', '12345678000112','joao','87654321000198','5');


my $c = 0;

my %hash;

foreach my $d ( @data )
{

    $hash{$head[$c]} = $d;

    $c++;

}

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Uma maneira simples de se fazer o de/para com os seus dados é a forma apresentada acima onde é criado um contador para [acessar as posições](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) necessárias do header e adicionando no hash.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade você não quer bem um hash como resposta, você quer um hash por linha, um array de hashes, senão você vai sobrescrever os elementos do seu hash.
Sendo assim, aqui vai o código modificado:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @head = ("nomeinstituicao", "cnpjinstituicao","nomecliente", "cnpjcliente", "notacliente");

my @data = ("inst1", "12345678000112","joao",  "87654321000198","5",
         "inst2","54387612000123","maria","45612387000123","6");


my @hash;
my $realhash;
for my $i (0..$#data) {
    my $coluna = $head[$i % $#head];
    if ($coluna eq "nomeinstituicao") {
        push @hash, $realhash if ($realhash);
        $realhash = {};
    }
    $realhash->{$coluna} = $data[$i];
}

print Dumper \@hash;
```

Este código produz o seguinte output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'nomecliente' => 'joao',
            'cnpjcliente' => '87654321000198',
            'cnpjinstituicao' => '12345678000112',
            'nomeinstituicao' => 'inst1'
          },
          {
            'cnpjinstituicao' => 'inst2',
            'cnpjcliente' => 'maria',
            'nomecliente' => '54387612000123',
            'nomeinstituicao' => '5'
          }
        ];
```

Se você está utilizando DBI, existe um método que faz isso tudo para você, sem você precisar construir os arrays `@head @data`, chama-se [`fetchall_hashref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_hashref)